# Using XSockets.NET in MVC 4 project. Project deploying on IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sockets, iis, websocket

For now I'm just have a little experience in web development. So, cannot be sure in second decision.

I'm restricted by `.NET 4.0`, ASP.NET MVC4 and `IIS 7.0` for application deploying.

Can i include to my MVC project `XSockets.NET` library?

Disturbs note on the main page [Note: **We do not recommend to host XSockets inside of IIS in test/production due to the fact that IIS recycles.**](http://xsockets.net/docs/installing-xsocketsnet) Which version Windows Server i restricted also ?

Comment: If you do not use state in XSockets you do not need to worry about the IIS recycle. Just use XSockets inside of IIS and rock on. If you use state in XSockets I would recomend you to use the windows service, azure, amazon, console app etc

Comment: @Uffe Thanks, very useful. I see you are competent in XSockets/ SignalR questions. May i ask you about one else?) How to resolve problem with connection between XSockets client and XSockets server in Mozilla FireFox. Got error "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:4502/****". Looked into theirs developer's forum i seen that I'm not alone in this problem

Comment: I have no such problem. What version are you using of javascript api and server api? Also what version of FF?

Comment: @Uffe FF 26.0, XSockets.JsApi 3.0.2, XSockets.Server and Core  3.0.4.1, XSockets.Plugin.Framework 1.4.1

Comment: I managed to reproduce your issue! Upgrade to latest version of XSockets nuget packages (both server and javascript) and you should be ok. Current version is 3.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per `Uffe's` First comment.

> If you do not use `state` in XSockets you do not need to worry about
>   the IIS recycle. Just use XSockets inside of IIS and rock on. If you
>   use state in XSockets I would recommend you to use the windows
>   service, azure, amazon, console app etc...

Comment: Just adding that as of XSockets 4.0 (now in alpha) there is OWIN support, so now you can host it with state where ever you want. OWIN = good, IIS = evil :)